# Get data from api using request-promise and express

Tags: node.js, express, request-promise

I'm trying to get in response the data stored in my api url.

Inside the router, I'm using request-promise to get data from the url.

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  let uri = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/donations';

  let _include_headers = function(body, response, resolveWithFullResponse) {
    return {'headers': response.headers, 'data': body};
  };

  let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: uri,
    json: true,
    transform: _include_headers,
  }

  return request(options)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(response.data);
  });
});
```

yet I'm getting this error `Unhandled rejection RequestError: Error: socket hang up`.

I'm a newbie and I don't know what does this error stands for? and what I'm I doing wrong?

Help would be precious.

Comment: Does the URL work alone? If you open the page at uri in browser, does it show the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.then`, you also need to use `.catch`
The code in `.then` runs when everything is OK, and the code in `.catch` runs when there is an error. 
In your case, the error occures, but there is no code that runs for that. What you need to do is:

```
return request(options)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.error('An error occured: ' + error);
  });
```

But that is just graceful processing of an error. What do you do with that "Socet hang up" error? This basically means that the software that you are making request to (the one that at http://localhost:3000/api/v1/donations) is accepted your connection but doesn't send any response in given time (usually, 30 sec). The problem is in that another software.

And another problem that I see in tour code, is that you need to do `res.send()` or `res.end()` somewhere in your code, or user will get an error, a blank page, or an endlessly loading page.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the source of the issue was that I wasn't declaring in the env variables the connection to the db. Once done, it rendered my array.

Answer (score 0):

**Need to handle error on request:** Check the error on the catch block.

```
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(403).send({message: error.message})
  });
```

**Need to restun response:**

```
 res.send(response.data)
```

**Complete:**

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  let uri = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/donations";
  let _include_headers = function (body, response, resolveWithFullResponse) {
    return { headers: response.headers, data: body };
  };
  let options = {
    method: "GET",
    uri: uri,
    json: true,
    transform: _include_headers,
  };
  request(options).then(function (response) {
    res.send(response.data)
  }).catch(error => {
    res.status(403).send({message: error.message})
  });
});
```